# Get value from ID field (jQuery UI issue)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this page:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/rangemin.html

I added a name attribute to the HTML code:

`<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" />`

When I get the value with PHP:

`<?php echo $_POST['amount'] ?>`

I get 0 not the the real amount (200 or 176 or 98 ...)

Comment: You have to have a name attribute to get it from request back on server side.

Comment: You could write something like: $("#amount").attr('name', $("#amount").attr('id'));

Comment: Can you manually set the value, without using the slider, and submit the form to see if you get the posted value. That will tell you if the value is getting there or not and will tell you if its an issue with your slider or not.

Comment: Ok so it looks like it's an issue with the slider itself, try adding a SPAN to your page somewhere you can see it, give it an id, then in your function for 'slide' add the line to set the text value of the SPAN. Like $('#testspan').text(ui.value); so that you can see the value is being update into the span correctly.

Comment: Oh my bad you have an input box. Makes what I just asked pointless. So when you slide the slider, the value in the input box updates correctly?

Comment: Wow, thats really strange then. Manually setting the value, you get the value serverside, letting the slider change the value, you see it update, but receive '0' serverside. I'm all out of idea's on what the issue could be sorry :(

Comment: You should only have one element with the id 'amount' on the page. But that shouldn't matter, if the input box value is being updated, you should be able to capture the value serverside by the given name. Tho you should only have 1 input box with the name 'amount'.

Comment: Many thanks. I just edited my original post (question). Can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming '$_POST' is PHP, only form elements with a name attribute are posted, if you have no name attribute that value wont be posted.

Comment: @Pascal.Potencier you should make friends with Google, first.

Comment: Try getting Firefox - Temper Data, or Fiddler, to capture the post request and see if the values are being posted. Without seeing your PHP or HTML it could be an issue clientside or serverside.

Comment: Your input element(s) & submit button are wrapped in a form element correct?

Comment: Of course yes. The title, tags, date fields are inserted correctly into the database :)

Comment: Ok, just checking :) try what i mentioned in the comment to your quest.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. Yes I did it and I get the correct value. but when I add the slider effect I get 0